# How to find all positive divisors of a given number?

Tags: divisibility

For example, I have to find all positive divisors of $372$. The prime factorization of $372$ is $2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 31$

Now, I wonder if there is a fast method to find **all** positive divisors of $372$.

Comment: Well, any divisor must have the form $2^a3^b31^c$ for $a\in \{0,1,2\}$ and $b,c\in \{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have the prime factorization of a number, say 
$$n=p_1^{n_1}\cdot p_2^{n_2}\cdots p_{r}^{n_r},$$
then any positive divisors $d$ of $n$ can be written as
$$d=p_1^{x_1}\cdot p_2^{x_2}\cdots p_{r}^{x_r}$$
where each exponent $x_i$ is a non-negative integer less or equal to $n_i$. The number of such divisors is equal to the product $(n_1+1)\cdot (n_2+1)\cdots (n_r+1)$.

In your example $n=372=2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 31^1$ and therefore the divisors are $3\cdot 2\cdot 2=12$ and they are
$$2^0 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 31^0$$
$$2^0 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 31^1$$
$$2^0 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 31^0$$
$$2^0 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 31^1$$
$$2^1 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 31^0$$
$$2^1 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 31^1$$
$$2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 31^0$$
$$2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 31^1$$
$$2^2 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 31^0$$
$$2^2 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 31^1$$
$$2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 31^0$$
$$2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 31^1$$

Comment: @RobertZ , thank you, but, my fault (of course), I have always had problems in understanding mathematical language. I wonder if there is an easier way to explain it. Let's say, less formal.

Comment: @Always learning Is it clear now?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! I am sorry...but I am very dumb in math. How do I know that "...therefore the divisors are 3⋅2⋅2=12..." ?

Comment: Because the exponent of $2$ can be $0,1,2$ (3 choices) , the exponent of $3$ can be $0,1$ (2 choices), the exponent of $31$ can be $0,1$ (2 choices). All these choices are independent and therefore the total number of combinations is the product $3\cdot 2\cdot 2=12$.

Comment: Now it is clear, thanks! So, is this the fasted method to find the positive divisors?

Comment: Once you have the factorization (the hard part if $n$ is big) then I don't see any other way to do it.

Comment: Thanks! I wait a while, but I will not forget then to mark this as a solution to my inquiry, in case.

Comment: @Always learning  You are welcome!

Comment: @Always this may well be fastest manual method. But suppose that it isn't. In that case it wouldn't be surprising (to me at least) that the fastest method was considerably more complicated. In other words there is often a trade off between fastest and most straightforward. Factoring numbers is good example. Factoring by trial division (using 2 and odd numbers) up to the square root is easy to understand and perform. But there are more complicated methods (trial division by primes) that are quicker and there are far more complicated methods (general number field sieve) that are quicker still.