# Divisors of $240$ of the form $2m+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, combinations

Just read a question where it was asked , ‘What is the number of divisors of $240$ that are of the form $4m+2$ ?’ According to the answer , the divisor must be of the from $2(2m+1)$
Hence the number of divisors is given by $1(1+1)(1+1) = 4$ 
But I was wondering , the $(1+1)$ also corresponds to the case where the odd divisors of $240$ i.e. $3$ and $5$ are not chosen at all simultaneously. How will I then get the odd divisor of the form $2m+1$ ?

Comment: Is $m$ strictly positive?

Comment: yes m is positive .

Answer (score 3):

$240=2^3\cdot3\cdot5$. If you want only odd (positive) divisors, you can just take the divisors of $3\cdot5=15$ so you get the four divisors $1,3,5$ and $15$.

Comment: Thank you , I was just wondering whether the factor $1$ corresponds to that way of choosing the divisors of $15$ when we leave $3$ and $5$ completely ?

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for positive divsors.  You are looking for odd divisors of $15=3\cdot 5$.  There are $(1+1)(1+1)$ of them because you can either take the $3$ or not for the first $(1+1)$ and you can take the $5$ or not for the other one.  If we list them there are $1,3,5,15$

Comment: To add to the specific question asked: If we leave out 3 and 5, then we have the divisor 2, which is of the form $4m + 2$ where $m=0$. Hence, we can also leave out 3 and 5 completely, yielding $2m + 1 = 1$.

Comment: Ohh okay thank you I understand it now !

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We wish to find it's odd divisors. First, let $m$ be the smallest number such that $m|n$ and $\frac{n}{m}$ is a power of $2$. This number exists by Well-Ordering Principle because the set of numbers with this property is bounded below by $1$ and non-empty (since $n$ itself falls in this set). Put another way, $m$ is the number $n$ with all the factors of $2$ taken out. Notice that $m$ and $n$ have exactly the same odd factors.

Since $m$ is odd, all of the factors of $m$ are odd, so we just need to find all the factors of $m$. This is straightforward and is detailed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361609/how-to-find-all-positive-divisors-of-a-given-number) if you don't know how.

In your case, $240=2^4\cdot 15$ and so $m=15$. The factors of $15$ are $\{1,3,5,15\}$.